# Active report : how to generate click event on table row

Tags: c#, activereports

I'm new in Active Reports. 
I'm using Active Reports version 13. I have created report and showing it in WPF application.
Now i want click event on each rows of table.
Is it possible? and answer is yes then please tell me how.

I search about this problem but i don't found any solution

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using ActiveReports.   I assume you mean a Table report item in the viewer.   There are no runtime events on these controls at runtime (they are basically a preview of a printed page).   However, if your intent is to add interaction to your table such as drill-down to a subreport or launch an external page, that is possible using hyperlinks and drilldown options.
If you can explain more about what you need to do with the event we can try to help.

Thank you.
[Grapecity ActiveReports Team](https://www.grapecity.com/activereports)